# Why I get 'u' even after initial the signal to '0'?

Tags: vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity TOP is port
(  
    CLOCK: in std_logic;
    Rdata_ADC: in std_logic;

    CLK2_ADC : out std_logic;
    CS_ADC  : out Std_logic;
    CS_DAC  : out Std_logic;
    SCK_DAC  : out std_logic;
    Mosi_ADC : out std_logic;
    Mosi_DAC : out std_logic
);

end TOP;

architecture behavioral of Top is
    signal Send_S, CLK2: std_logic;
    signal MOSI_DAC_S: std_logic :='0';
    Signal CS_DAC_S: std_logic :='0';
    signal DOUT_VALUE: std_logic_vector (11 downto 0) :="000000000000";
begin

    A0: ENTITY work.ADC(behavioral) port map
        (CLK=> CLOCK, R_DATA=> Rdata_ADC, CS=> CS_ADC, MOSI=> Mosi_ADC,
       CLk2=> CLk2, SEND=> Send_S, Dout=> DOUT_VALUE);

    A1: entity work.DAC(behavioral) port map
        (SCK=> SCK_DAC, CS=> CS_DAC_S, MOSI=> MOSI_DAC_S, 
        CLK2=> CLK2, SEND=> SEND_S, Value=> DOUT_Value);

   CLK2_ADC <= CLK2;
   MOSI_DAC <= MOSI_DAC_S;
    CS_DAC <= CS_DAC_S;

End behavioral;
```

[image]

Why I get 'u' even after initial the signal MOSI_DAC_S and CS_DAC_S to '0'?

Comment: It comes about because you're assigning `MOSI_DAC <= MOSI_DAC_S;` and `CS_DAC <= CS_DAC_S;`. You defined an initial value for the inner signals but there is one for the actual signals connected via a port map. These don't have initial values.  They don't get updated until events on the right hand side signals. There is no guarantee of execution order between concurrent statements.

Comment: Don't go around putting default values on signals, though. Never use default values in synthesizable VHDL (except in rare cases), it gives misleading results and reduces portability. Implement a proper reset scheme instead, taken from an externally or internally generated reset source.

Comment: @TonyM Is there an FPGA tool chain that doesn't support initial values? Not everyone is in a position where they need to worry about their design being ported into an ASIC flow.

Comment: @scary_jeff yes, lots of CPLDs as well as many Microsemi and Lattice parts. Who said ASICs? Not everyone is using RAM-based FPGAs. I design into a very wide range of devices for different projects. Don't use initial values in synthesizable logic. Fine for testbenches only.

Comment: @TonyM OK, what are the rare cases where you can use them?

Comment: @scary_jeff implementing an internal post-initialisation reset generator in a RAM-based FPGA when there's no external reset. Then I use a shift register, initialised with 0's and shifting in 1's, with big comments pointing out the oddity to be avoided. Not being dramatic, it's on 'the list' of digital design don't's and so, so easy to use reset instead. Do you use them a lot then?

Comment: @TonyM Without an HDL 'reset' for a register, the register's SR pin can be exploited in synthesis to reduce the number of logic levels. Without this, I would have to use a faster speed grade device for some designs. That being said, the majority of the initial states don't matter in these designs; take a 2-page buffer as an example, the toggle signal initial state doesn't matter, but without initialisation, it won't work in simulation.

Comment: @scary_jeff, but most people won't use such tricks with the asynchronous SR and you're citing a more niche situation (which was your opening point with me). Not using reset is fine but don't use initial values in VHDL as a general scheme, too many pitfalls. Other engineers need to maintain/develop designs and they may not navigate these minefields as well as the author. Anyway, you get the theme of the point and it's commonly recommended, trawl the Internet. Actually, don't, there's too much deplorable VHDL out there.

Comment: @TonyM yep, and my point is that in general, there are valid use cases even for things that are commonly recommended against.

Comment: @scary_jeff, no, it's not good practice. I get that you like it but... anyway, I've made the same point over and over. Can move to chat if you want to set that up otherwise I wish you well and will leave it there.

Comment: `use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;` <== not needed in this file. Furthermore, it arithmetic is required, preferably use `use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;`

Answer (score 2):

You have `'U'` on the wires because it connected from internal module and probably appropriate signals weren't initialize there. So if you initialize the signals in internal module you will not get `'U'`. 
 You have to initialize signals which connected to `CS` and `MOSI` outputs in module `DAC`.